# Storing biological classification

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm developing a website which will store the [biological classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_classification) of various venomous animals - I'll need to keep Kingdom -> (Sub)Species.

From Family down I'd like to keep a similar set of information:

- excerpt
- physical description
- geographic range
- habitat
- diet
- behavior
- lifespan
- venom
- reproduction
- captivity

Obviously the further down the classification tree we go the more specific the information would get.

I'm trying to work out the best way to store this data, obviously I could just have a table for each taxon, but this doesn't seem like the best way to me.

What I'm thinking is using [Laravel's Polymorphic Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations) and something like this (still very much a work in progress):

#### kingdom

- id - small int pk ai
- slug - vchar(60)
- name - vchar(60)

#### phylum

- id - small int pk ai
- slug - vchar(60)
- name - char(60)

#### subphylum

- id - small int pk ai
- slug - vchar(60)
- name - vchar(60)

#### class

- id - small int pk ai
- slug - vchar(60)
- name - vchar(60)

#### order

- id - small int pk ai
- slug - vchar(60)
- name - vchar(60)

#### suborder

- id - small int pk ai
- slug - vchar(60)
- name - vchar(60)

#### family

- id - small int pk ai
- slug - vchar(60)
- name - vchar(60)

#### subfamily

- id - small int pk ai
- slug - vchar(60)
- name - vchar(60)

#### genus

- id - small int pk ai
- slug - vchar(60)
- name - vchar(60)

#### species

- id - small int pk ai
- slug - vchar(60)
- name - vchar(60)

#### subspecies

- id - small int pk ai
- slug - vchar(60)
- name - vchar(60)

#### metadata

- id - small int pk ai
- taxa_id - small int
- taxa_type - small vchar
- slug - vchar(60)
- kingdom_id - small int fk
- phylum_id - small int fk
- subphylum_id - small int fk
- class_id - small int fk
- order_id - small int fk
- suborder_id - small int fk
- family_id - small int fk
- subfamily_id - small int fk
- genus_id - small int fk
- species_id - small int fk
- subspecies_id - small int fk nullable
- conservation_status_id - small int fk
- excerpt - vchar(255)
- physicalDescription - text
- geographicRange - text
- habitat - text
- diet - text
- behavior - text
- lifespan - text
- venom - text
- reproduction - text
- captivity - text

I don't really care about listing specific information (it won't be any use to my users anyway) about Kingdom -> Suborder - so perhaps I could handle them slightly differently.

What could I improve, or do I need to go away and totally rethink this?

Comment: For any kind of classification I would go for Nested sets, since they seem to be the most performant solution for getting classification tree the entity belongs to. Take a look at this package.
https://packagist.org/packages/baum/baum

Comment: This looks really handy - cheers I'll take a stab at this later!